# HTML cards images size makes card size different

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Good day,

NO matter what i try or what tutorial i use, the card size images are not the same.

A user uploads a image and then the cards needs to scale the image up or down but the total card size across should stay the same width and height.

one image is 2956 x 1965
and the second image is 1024 x 683

the below code looks right until you use different images sizes.
i don't want to upload 100's of images with the same sizes

Below is a screenshot and the code
[enter image description here][1]

```css
<style>

.column_main {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 900px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}




/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column_main {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
}

div.polaroid {
  width:100%;

       overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-bottom: 25px;


}

div.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>



 

<div class="row">
 
 
 
 
  <div class="column">

<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="img_nature2.jpg" alt="5 Terre" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
  <p>Title</p>
  </div>
</div>





  </div>
 
 
  <div class="column">
   
<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="img_nature1.jpg" alt="5 Terre"style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
  <p>Title</p>
  </div>
</div>
   
  </div>
  
  
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Good question. Only the image is missing. On first sight both cards look the same. I didn't measure it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a default css to the img or its parent div element

```css
.card{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: black solid 1px; //Look clearly with border :)
}

.card-image{
  width:100%;
  height:150px; //Whatever you want for only image
  object-fit: cover; // it is important for scale of image
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/vancouver_image_conference_3-scaled.jpg" class="card-image">
    <p>Card Title</p>
</div>
```